# "Safely" terminate a running C++ program on keypress?

Tags: c++, keyboard, exit

I'm trying to write a simulation that will carry on running until I press a certain key (like 'q' for quit). Then after I press that, I want the program to finish writing the data its currently writing, close files, then gracefully exit (as opposed to just pressing ctrl+c to force the program to stop). Is there any way to do this on C++?

Thanks

Comment: There is certainly a way to do this. You'll need to break out of your simulation loops somehow, but detecting the keypress is going to be the kicker. On what OS will this program run?

Comment: Seems a rather broad question. 1) How do I read a key asynchronously? 2) How do I notify the program to shutdown? 3) How to make sure all the data are written before finalizing the shutdown?

Comment: You will need to find the operating system libraries to perform this function. It is not as Standard.

Comment: You can use `select()` on `stdin` to see if it is available for reading.

Comment: There be more magic that needs to be done. Most terminals buffer until Enter is pressed, for instance.

Comment: This is gonna be run on linux or mac. Preferably I'd like it to be non-os dependent, but if it's the only option then something unix compatible. Basically I was hoping there was a way to 'listen' for a keypress so that at the end of every iteration of the simulation, it would check if that key had been pressed, then call a shutdown function.

Comment: @pst: The question does not say if this is meant for linux, windows or mac os. So in general it cannot be done at all. The C++ standard gives no way to do it, but operating system can provide more facilities. The way to do this will be different on each system.

Comment: You can't `select` on `stdin`. `stdin` is a `FILE*`, not a file descriptor. You *can* `select` on standard input, i.e. `0`.

Comment: @pst true, but you can solve that by changing the requirement. Let the user press Enter to stop the sim, instead of "q".

Answer (score 5):

Have the user press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, but install a signal handler to deal with it. In the signal handler, set a global boolean variable, for example `user_wants_to_quit`. Then your sim loop can look like:

```
while ( work_to_be_done && !user_wants_to_quit) {
 …
}
// Loop exited, clean up my data
```

A complete POSIX program (sorry, if you were hoping for Microsoft Windows), including setting and restoring the SIGINT (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) handler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

namespace {
  sig_atomic_t user_wants_to_quit = 0;

  void signal_handler(int) {
    user_wants_to_quit = 1;
  }
}

int main () {

  // Install signal handler
  struct sigaction act;
  struct sigaction oldact;
  act.sa_handler = signal_handler;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &act, &oldact);


  // Run the sim loop
  int sim_loop_counter = 3;
  while( (sim_loop_counter--) && !user_wants_to_quit) {
    std::cout << "Running sim step " << sim_loop_counter << std::endl;

    // Sim logic goes here. I'll substitute a sleep() for the actual
    // sim logic
    sleep(1);

    std::cout << "Step #" << sim_loop_counter << " is now complete." << std::endl;
  }

  // Restore old signal handler [optional]
  sigaction(SIGINT, &oldact, 0);

  if( user_wants_to_quit ) {
    std::cout << "SIM aborted\n"; 
  } else {
    std::cout << "SIM complete\n";
  }

}
```